# Validation of the structure of the files within an SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I currently have the following flow:

[image]

The information on the left comes from a file called Compras.asl, the flow does it correctly, what I need to do is validate the structure of the file, which has the correct structure, my question is, how can I perform this validation of the metadata without having to write a stored procedure? I want to do it within the flow as such, is it possible to do this?

Comment: If the file is not in the correct structure, the package will throw a metadata validation warning. If a column is missing, the package will fail. If you want to validate beforehand it you need to use a script task (this is not in the data flow, it's in the control flow)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "validate the structure of the file"?   It's pretty vague.

Comment: I hope you understand Tab Alleman. For example, that the document that is uploaded, of any of the 2 sides, carries the number of correct columns and at the same time that they have the correct types of values. This is why the file is an .asl format that comes from a transformation of an excel file.